# SonarQube and squidS2095 with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

I have a problem with SonarQube. The code below

```
StreamSupport.stream(var, false).mapToInt().collect(..);
```

does not comply with the rule

> squid: S2095 Resources should be closed

What can I do to tell SonarQube to not scan features from Java 8 to that rule?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer. This is a known bug:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1478